# How to change text size for a Status Widget in GXT

Tags: gxt, java-6

I need to create a info message for a FieldSet which contains a grid. I am setting the message using:

```
Status status = new Status();
status.setText("You can choose max 40 persons");
status.addStyleName("x-form-info-tip");
```

But in the output, the text looks really big, so how can I change the text size for this Status message?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try

status.setAttribute("font-size","45px");

Comment: status.setStyleAttribute(attr, value);